# How to be write in cells in SharePoint cells?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, list-form

I have a list in SharePoint with rows and columns. The problem is that I'm not able to write any text in one of my columns.

How do I change the information type in a column so that I can write text in it?

Comment: What permissions you have on the list, full control or edit or read?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? If I understand correctly you have an existing site column on a list that you want to write any text within, but since you can't I think the column is of a different type than text. If that is correctly understood you cannot change the type but would have to create a new site column within the list to add you text. Let me know if that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have [Edit or higher permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) on the SharePoint list and you have created the required columns in the list - [Create a column in a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Then you can create new items in the list using **+New** button (single item at a time) or using **Edit in grid view** option (multiple items at a time).

**+New option**: I will open the list form where you can enter the information and save:

[image]

**Edit in grid view option**:

You can also use "Edit in grid view" option next to +New option to edit multiple items, which will open like excel file where you can edit multiple cells at a time and then click **Exit grid view** to save the changes:

[image]

This option should be enabled for new SharePoint list by default, if it is not available in your list, you can enable it by following this article: [Enable or Disable Quick property editing (Grid view) from SharePoint Online list](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/27/disable-quick-property-editing-grid-view-from-sharepoint-online-list/).

Comment: This post is under construcion

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. But it seems like I havnen't explained my question well enough. I'm not able to post screen shots in this comment so I am posting my screen shots in "Answer your own question".  Could you look at my screen shots in that post?

Comment: You can "Edit" your original question to provide more details, check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLDQt.png. Are you using list or library? Did you create the "Name" column or is it SharePoint default column? I think you are using some kind of lookup column. Can you show what is the issue when you are editing information from list form or list view?